# Can a DataTemplate be placed inside another DataTemplate of different Template Structure?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I want a DataTemplate for ListBox having the ItemsSource as Collection of Borders. Inside each Border i want to display another ListBox containg set of some items having its own ItemsSource.
But, when i try to acheive this structure i am not able to populate any data.

My XAML code -

```
 <Grid x:Name="RightPanel" Grid.Column="2" Background="Beige">
            <Border  BorderBrush="Black" Margin="4" BorderThickness="1.5">
                  <ScrollViewer  Margin="2"  Focusable="False">
                    <ListBox x:Name="MainRightListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ListBoxCollection,Mode=TwoWay}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ListBox x:Name="ChildListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentPage.ClonedVectorImages,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding ImageVectorSelected}"  BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent">
                                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel x:Name="canvas" Background="Transparent" Orientation="Horizontal" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}, Mode=FindAncestor}}">
                                                <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                                                    <ContextMenu>
                                                        <MenuItem Header="Delete" CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                                    Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.DeleteCloneCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}, Mode=FindAncestor}}"/>
                                                    </ContextMenu>
                                                </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                                                <Viewbox Width="35" Height="35" >
                                                    <Canvas Width="35" Height="35">
                                                        <Canvas>
                                                            <Path Fill="#ffda2526" Data="F1 M 0.000,112.500 C 0.000,50.369 50.368,0.000 112.500,0.000 C 174.632,0.000 225.000,50.369 225.000,112.500 C 225.000,174.633 174.632,225.000 112.500,225.000 C 50.368,225.000 0.000,174.633 0.000,112.500 Z" Height="30.667" Stretch="Fill" Width="31"/>
                                                            <TextBlock x:Name="tb1" Text="{Binding CountId}" Foreground="WhiteSmoke" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Arial Bold" Height="20" RenderTransformOrigin="1.588,1.224" Canvas.Left="9.322" Canvas.Top="3.335"></TextBlock>
                                                        </Canvas>
                                                    </Canvas>
                                                </Viewbox>

                                                <TextBox Text="Enter Text Here" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>

                </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

> "*Can a DataTemplate be placed inside another DataTemplate of different Template Structure?*"

The answer is yes, it can. Your XAML structure is fine.

But what possibly wrong is binding path/expression used. You need to be aware that `DataContext` of the inner `ListBox` (the one inside `DataTemplate`) is corresponding *item* in `ListBoxCollection`. So if that *item* mentioned before has property `CurrentPage.ClonedVectorImages`, this way of binding should work fine to populate the inner `ListBox` :

```
<ListBox x:Name="ChildListBox" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentPage.ClonedVectorImages,Mode=TwoWay}" 
         ........>
```

Comment: I created ListBoxCollection only in order to give Some ItemSource for my Outer ListBox, so ListBoxCollection is only the collection of dynamically created Borders. Inside these individual borders i want to  place my InnerListbox Items. So my View is Something like this - Border 1(listboxItem1, listBoxItem2, ....) Border2(listBoxItem3,.....) Border3(...) , ..... Can i achieve this View from same XAML structure?

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, I think you can't. Your current XAML markup means, you'll have one ListBox filled with ListBoxItems for each Border. This is wrong way if you want to have ListBoxItems directly inside Border, and those ListBoxItems are continuous across Borders.

Comment: Ok got it. Can you suggest any other way or Example from where i can see how to create the same view as i have mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `DataTemplates` in resources with the corresponding keys, because otherwise an exception may occur:

> Markup.IStyle.Connector.Connect error

This is bug of studio, which is described as follows [`link`](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/560631/net-framework-4-0-regression-in-wpf-exception-in-istyleconnector-connect-with-nested-itemscontrols-and-event-style-attributes-in-datatemplate):

> A good way to look at this problem “Templating is like parentheses, quoting parentheses” the Template XAML is not created but saved and run later. The bug is therefore: We have a problem with nested parentheses.

In any case as I think, should be avoided nesting templates and use him via resources, it will be easier and clearer.